# "They are British, so am I"

Tags: conjunctions

In the following sentence, is it correct to use a comma to link the two clauses, i.e., "They are British" and "so am I"?

> They are British, so am I.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence is comprehensible as you have written it, but I would say that “They are British; so am I.” is more natural/strictly correct.

If you want to use a comma rather than a semi-colon, “They are British, and so am I.” would work.